# how to transform image w/ cartopy & rioxarray ...?

Tags: python-xarray, cartopy, rasterio

I'd like to read an image (w/ georef info) w/ rioxarray (or rasterio) and plot it w/ cartopy w/ a transform :

```
import rioxarray

fn2 = 'https://eoimages.gsfc.nasa.gov/images/imagerecords/144000/144898/BlackMarble_2016_01deg_geo.tif'
da0 = rioxarray.open_rasterio(fn2)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig0 = plt.figure()

import cartopy

proj0 = cartopy.crs.LambertConformal(-100)

ax0 = fig0.add_subplot(111, projection = proj0)

ax0.coastlines()
ax0.gridlines()

da0.plot.imshow(ax = ax0, transform = da0.rio.crs)
plt.show()
```

... but I get an error :

ValueError: Expected a projection subclass. Cannot handle a <class 'rasterio.crs.CRS'> in imshow

Answer (score 0):

This is because cartopy only deals with projections defined as subclasses of `cartopy.CRS` (as far as i know there's not yet a support for arbitrary projections defined via wkt-strings etc.)

However, I'm the dev of [EOmaps](https://github.com/raphaelquast/EOmaps) which is based on cartopy but handles re-projections directly with `pyproj`.
As such it is perfectly capable of using arbitrary input projections:

```py
from eomaps import Maps
import rioxarray

fn2 = 'https://eoimages.gsfc.nasa.gov/images/imagerecords/144000/144898/BlackMarble_2016_01deg_geo.tif'
da0 = rioxarray.open_rasterio(fn2)
# EOmaps expects a xar.Dataset not a xar.DataArray
da0 = da0.to_dataset(name="blackmarble")

m = Maps(Maps.CRS.LambertConformal(-100))
m.new_layer_from_file.GeoTIFF(da0, set_extent=False)
m.ax.gridlines()
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome ! That's very concise . Thanks !

Comment: FYI, in Fedora, before doing 'pip install eomaps' I first installed : dnf install python3-mapclassify python3-cairosvg python3-xmltodict

Comment: @klueless hey, thx for mentioning this! would you be willing to share your installation process for eomaps using pip on linux? (maybe as a [discussion](https://github.com/raphaelquast/EOmaps/discussions) on github)... I'm using conda for all my package-dependencies, but I had some questions regarding how to install eomaps directly with pip on linux which I can't really answer so your insights would be highly appreciated)